# Exiting Python Debugger ipdb

Tags: python, debugging, workflow, exit, ipdb

I use ipdb fairly often in a way to just jump to a piece of code that is *isolated* i.e. it is hard to write a real script that uses it. Instead I write a minimal test case with mocking and jump into it.

Exemplary for the workflow:

```
def func():
   ...
   import ipdb
   ipdb.set_trace()
   ...

def test_case():
    ...
    func()
    ...
```

Then, invoke

```
py.test test_file.py -s -k test_case
```

Now, usually I just check one variable or two, and then want to quit. Change the code and do it over again.

How do I quit? The manual says `q` quits the debugger. It doesn't (really). You have to quit a few times before the debugger actually terminates. The same behavior for Ctrl-C and Ctrl-D (with the additional frustration that hitting Ctrl-D several times eventually quits the terminal, too).

Is there a smart way to force quit? Is this workflow even sensible? What is the standard way to do it?

Comment: I'm getting this now too. This is recent behavior. It used to ctrl-c just fine but now it just won't quit. even throwing an exception won't stop it.

Comment: Link to [GitHub issue](https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb/issues/111) about this problem.

Comment: the original problem has been solved in ipython 5.2, see @cheflo's answer. Can you accept it as the answer not to confuse other people with the suggested workarounds?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I put the following in my `.pdbrc`

```
import os

alias kk os.system('kill -9 %d' % os.getpid())
```

`kk` kills the debugger and (the process that trigger the debugger).

Comment: It would work but looks like a workaround rather than a solution of the problem.  Did you try to ask ipdb developers of it? BTW looks like a similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39090752/how-to-quit-ipdb-while-in-post-mortem-debugging

Comment: Yes, I agree it is a work-around. One of the downsides of this work-around is that if you invoke the debugger from an ipython console with `%debug` and use my `kk` macro it will not just quit the debugger but also kill the ipython console. It should be raised with the developers.

Comment: Where is the .pdbrc file? Do you have to create it if it doesn't exist already?

Comment: Shouldn't be `alias kk import os; os.system('kill -9 %d' % os.getpid())` in case `os` is not imported?

Comment: For Linux/Mac plus Windows let it be: 
`import os; import platform;

terminate_cmd = 'kill -9 %d' % os.getpid() if platform.system() != 'Windows' else 'taskkill /F /PID %d' % os.getpid();
alias kk os.system(terminate_cmd)` on different lines

Answer (score 55):

The following worked for me:

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

On newer versions of ipython, as mentioned above and below, this doesn't work.
In that case,

```
import os
os._exit(0)
```

should still do the trick.

Comment: This isn't working for me. I just get "*** SystemExit: -1" on the console and I'm still in ipdb.

Answer (score 7):

It's the problem with the recent version of IPython 5.1.0. You can check with your environment using the following code:

```
pip freeze | egrep -i '^i'
```

It will be resolved by downgraded to IPython==5.0.0.

```
pip install ipython==5.0.0
```

That works for me.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in another answer, this was a bug in IPython 5.1. It was fixed in [this pull request](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/10009) and is no longer an issue from IPython 5.2 and onwards. You can now use `q`, `quit()`, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to exit the debugger.

Comment: Just tested it and it works fine for me. I think it should be the accepted answer as from ipython 5.2 onwards the suggested workarounds don't make sense

Comment: @DarkStar1 It works for me in a loop, can you post a sample of what does not work?

Comment: I'm using ipython 6.1.0 and ipdb 0.10.3; if the trace is set inside the loop, q just advances to the next iteration of the loop and I still have to use os._exit(0)

Comment: @thumbtackthief I just tested this again and it is still working for me to exit the debugger while inside a loop. Python 3.6.4, IPython 6.2.1, ipdb 0.11, Linux. Can you post an example of what is not working for you?

Comment: There is also this related issue: https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb/issues/111

Answer (score 2):

Sloppy but effective way is to set monkey patch `ipdb.set_trace = lambda:0`, then every subsequent time `ipdb.set_trace` is hit it will do nothing and return to the calling function. So you won't have to type `q` any more.

Comment: Very useful when you don't want to actually "kill" the process that called ipdb. This will keep you in the ipdb scope, but will run the parent process to completion.

Answer (score 0):

I've found these solutions only succeed in breaking your kernel, and then you have to restart and load everything again.

The problem I was having was in a for loop `q` will just proceed to the next iteration instead of quitting out of the loop. Eventually I figured out it only happens if your `for` loop is in a `try` statement. Remove the `try` and you can quit out of the debugger again without it continuing the `for` loop.