# How to quit ipdb while in post-mortem debugging?

Tags: python, ipython, pdb, ipdb

I like to inspect error in a Python script by using:

```
$ python3 -m pdb my_script.py
```

This drops me into a pdb prompt from where I can `c` continue the execution, and when it hits error, I can inspect the variables and then `q` quit the script execution to get back to my shell.

I tried the same with iPython debugger module, since it is more colorful:

```
$ python3 -m ipdb my_script.py
```

However, I am not able to quit the debugger once I am done inspecting the error. Using the `q` quit command just keeps switching it between re-executing the script and post-mortem mode:

```
$ python3 -m ipdb my_script.py
ipdb> c
Uncaught exception. Entering post mortem debugging
Running 'cont' or 'step' will restart the program
ipdb> Inspect some variables at this point
ipdb> q
Post mortem debugger finished. The my_script.py will be restarted
ipdb> q
Uncaught exception. Entering post mortem debugging
Running 'cont' or 'step' will restart the program
ipdb> q
Post mortem debugger finished. The my_script.py will be restarted
ipdb> q
Uncaught exception. Entering post mortem debugging
Running 'cont' or 'step' will restart the program
ipdb> q
Post mortem debugger finished. The my_script.py will be restarted
ipdb> q
Uncaught exception. Entering post mortem debugging
Running 'cont' or 'step' will restart the program
```

How to quit this debugger?

Comment: Does ^C or ^D not work? I've occasionally gotten something similar and had to ^C several times to exit

Comment: @spruceb That doesn't work either!

Comment: Worst comes to worst, ^Z, then a `kill %1` should stop it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exiting Python Debugger ipdb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32055062/exiting-python-debugger-ipdb)

Comment: What's your ipython version? This problem does reproduce in ipython==5.1.1. Check out this comment: https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb/issues/111

Comment: ^Z does not work either. ipdb catches it and displays `^Z`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This was a bug in IPython 5.1. It was fixed in [this pull request](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/10009) and is no longer an issue from IPython 5.2 and onwards. You can now use `q`, `quit()`, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to exit the debugger.

Comment: quit operation seems like slower than than using `pdb` itself. Is it a normal case?

Comment: Quitting the debugger is immediate for me.

Comment: Seems like it jumps to the next breakpoint instead of quitting when I do `q`

Answer (score 46):

As the user @ffeast commented, there is [an open ipdb issue](https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb/issues/111), and a few workarounds suggested. For me these worked well:

- press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> and `kill %1` (or whatever the Job number is)
- execute `ipdb> import os; os._exit(1)`

Comment: `ctrl+z` won't really exit the process, it just sends it to the background. For example, you can get back into the debugger by using the command `fg 1`, you will see the debugger is still there. The second one `import os; os._exit(1)` worked in my case.

Comment: True, updated answer with a follow up to kill bg process.

Comment: Can `import os; os._exit(1)` be set to an alias within `ipdb`?

Answer (score 3):

Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> or open a second terminal, then look for the process (`ps -ax | grep python`) and ***kill the process***.

Step by Step:

1. Get access to a terminal:

   - **Option A**: Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>
   - **Option B**: If *you have access to a the Ubuntu GUI*, open a second terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>)
   - **Option C**: If *you only have access to a command line*, access a second tty (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>)
   - **Option D**: If *you are accessing a server through ssh*, make a new connection from another terminal `ssh server` (use option B or C, so you can open a second connection to execute the command)
2. Look for the corresponding python `PID` of the process `ps -ax | grep python`. For example, the process id for my process (`python my_stucked_process.py`) would be `112923`:

```
   3085 tty1     Sl+   15:53 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator
   112923 pts/2    Tl     0:01 python my_stucked_process.py
   113118 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto python
```

3. Kill the process `kill -9 112923`

---

@tutuDajuju suggested using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> but their suggestion will only send the process to the background (it will still exists consuming memory). You need to do the abovein order to really kill the process