# Stuck in Ipython debugger loop

Tags: python, ipython

Everytime I press 'q', I get redirected to another ipdb session. I could just close the terminal window, but is there a better to kill the loop?

Comment: Type `exit()` or ctrl+d?

Comment: You can try `[CTRL]+Z`, use the `ps` command to find the PID and the `kill` command to wipe it.

Comment: Nope and nope. Both commands enter another loop.

Answer (score 5):

The main way I use to exit the loop is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>.

Otherwise, it is also possible to execute:

```
ipdb> import os; os._exit(1)
```

Here's a source to corroborate: [How to quit ipdb while in post-mortem debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39090752/how-to-quit-ipdb-while-in-post-mortem-debugging)

Comment: ding ding ding! thank you!

Comment: @Sebastian Consider accepting this answer if it helped you. It helps the community. :)

Comment: @COLDSPEED I'd love to. Is there a StackOverflow on how to accept the answer?