# how to break out of ipdb debugger?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipdb

How do you exit the ipdb debugger? According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32055062/exiting-python-debugger-ipdb) typing `q` should just work. I am on Python 3.6.6, Ipython 6.4.0 and that does not work in the following context: I have a function, `f(x)`, that is called from another function in a loop. After 2 iterations I just want to stop evaluation and exit the debugger. My `f(x)` just looks like this:

```
def f(x):
    ipdb.set_trace()
```

Literally meant to allow me to inspect `x` at runtime. However, typing `q` does not exit the debugger. Typing `os._exit(0)` kills the kernel. There must be something better? This is within a jupyter notebook.

Comment: Ctrl-D should work fine here. At least that's what I do.

Comment: that's mapped to a browser shortcut, what is ctr-d?

Comment: Oh, apologies this is in jupyter. Have you read [this](https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb/issues/111)? It's a closed issue, so it might provide details on a solution. Sorry, not much help. I'm not a jupyter user.

Comment: indeed that appears to be the issue, but i'm on a much later version and it looks like still having this problem... i think i may stop being a jupyter user very soon as well

Comment: Silly suggestion, but have you tried another browser just to see if there might be browser-specific shenanigans happening?

Comment: haven't, on chrome, worth a try but i think pretty unlikely

Comment: on a random note: what do you use to develop if not the jupyter group of products?

Comment: I use [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/).

Answer (score 2):

as i remember this used to be a bug in IPython 5.1, you can try Ctrl+d to exit the debugger, or quit(), or you can use Ctrl+z.

Last thing you can try is Ctrl+c.

Comment: Well last thing you can use is Click on the menu "Kernel" select "restart" and click  on the button "restart".

Comment: that's the same effect as `os._exit(0)`, i don't want to kill the kernel and have to rerun the whole notebook to get back to my last dev point